# Getting no such file or directory while installing ply using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, npm, automated-tests

I came across this cool project around Rest API testing framework. I was installing ply from https://github.com/ply-ct/ply

```
npm install ply-ct --save-dev
```

Got following error, does anyone know how to solve this

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ma/ply/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ma/ply/package.json'
npm WARN ply No description
npm WARN ply No repository field.
npm WARN ply No README data
npm WARN ply No license field.

+ ply-ct@2.1.3
added 89 packages from 73 contributors and audited 89 packages in 9.668s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction to run `npm install ply-ct --save-dev` presupposes that you have a node.js project with a [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) file.

If you just want to run the ply command-line interface for API testing, you can choose to install ply-ct globally:

```
npm install -g ply-ct
```

https://github.com/ply-ct/ply#installation

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to Ply.

Answer (score 0):

To be strict, it's not an **error**, just a warning (I believe you should be able to `require` this particular module in your sources). Because there's no `package.json` file in the directory where you install your dependency, `npm` was unable to add the file to your devDependencies.

To create the `package.json` file, you have to run `npm init` and answer some questions: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file.

After package.json shows up in your bare directory and you run `npm install ply-ct --save-dev` again, warning will no longer be there and after installation the dependency will be added to your `package.json` file. Later on, you'll simply have to run `npm install` to install all required dependencies.